# How To Use Storyboard?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5, storyboard

I'm trying to use storyboards segue instead of didSelectRowAtIndex.

This is what I have, but this method does not recognize indexPath.row.  Is there an alternative I can use to do the same thing?

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender 
{
    SpecificExerciseTableViewController *upcomingViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Web"]) 
    {
        upcomingViewController.exerciseArray = [[self.muscleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"exercises"];
        upcomingViewController.muscleName = [[self.muscleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"muscleName"];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless you have that indexPath as an ivar, no such variable exists in the scope.

If you would like to get the indexPath for the selected row in a UITableView use:

```
- (NSIndexPath *)indexPathForSelectedRow
```

The adjusted code for above:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender 
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

    SpecificExerciseTableViewController *upcomingViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Web"]) 
    {
        upcomingViewController.exerciseArray = [[self.muscleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"exercises"];
        upcomingViewController.muscleName = [[self.muscleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"muscleName"];
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried doing `NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];` but its giving me a null when I NSLog it.

Comment: It should return nil if there is no selected row, if it's still returning nil. Then possibly the tableView property is nil. It's difficult to say without more information.

Comment: Thanks so much - getting the NSIndexPath was what I was after. All sorted.

Answer (score 0):

This trick works fine,heres an example of how I used it to pull parsed elements into a web view

**.h file**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *url;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWebView *webView;
```

**.m file**

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"WebViewSegue"]) {

        WebViewController *webViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        webViewController.url = (self.parseResults)[indexPath.row][@"link"];
        webViewController.title = (self.parseResults)[indexPath.row][@"title"];

    }
}
```